# Module build failed in React

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I created a ui component and published it in npm.

`npm i @izy-ui/react-floating-button`

But after i create a new react project, installed above component.
But react show bellow error message.

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/@izy-ui/react-floating-button/index.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\PCName\Documents\clone\sample\my-app\node_modules\@izy-ui\react-floating-button\index.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (17:5):

  15 |   }
  16 |   return (
> 17 |     <>
     |     ^
  18 |       <div className={`float-container ${props.direction}`}>
  19 |         <div className="wrapper">
  20 |           <div onClick={handleClick} className={status ? `rotate button-styling-hidden ${props.basecolor} ` : `normal  button-styling-hidden ${props.basecolor}`}>

Add @babel/preset-react (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-react) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-jsx) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
    at instantiate (C:\Users\PCName\Documents\clone\sample\my-app\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:67:32)
```

`

What are the errors in created ui component? or what are the suggestions to solve this error

Comment: The error message provides at least two suggestions to solve this error.

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: @DaveNewton but i tried to solve it. i failed. do you have any idea to solve it?

Comment: @kennarddh yes, i used  `npx create-react-app`

Comment: Do you have access to the babel configuration? Can you edit it?

Comment: @kennarddh never setup or changed it before. also there have no any `babel.config.js` file

Comment: Can you try to remove `node_modules` and run `npm i`

Comment: @kennarddh now i tried it. it also fail

Comment: Try update react?

Comment: What react version does your new project run with?

Comment: Have you solved it?